# Invalid Memory Access on QueryContextAttributes using JNA

Tags: java, jna, sspi

I am attempting to use JNA to invoke the [QueryContextAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379326(v=vs.85).aspx) function in the Secur32.dll on Windows. I am unable to get the invocation correct for the SECPKG_ATTR_SIZES call. I have an implementation working for SECPKG_ATTR_NAMES and SECPKG_ATTR_PACKAGE_INFO. Therefore, I presume (famous last words) the issue is in the definition of the structure, or something about the invocation.

The Microsoft function definition for QueryContextAttributes is:

```
SECURITY_STATUS SEC_Entry QueryContextAttributes(
  _In_  PCtxtHandle phContext,
  _In_  ULONG       ulAttribute,
  _Out_ PVOID       pBuffer
 );
```

The Microsoft structure definition for the [SecPkgContext_Sizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380097(v=vs.85).aspx) is:

```
typedef struct _SecPkgContext_Sizes {
  ULONG cbMaxToken;
  ULONG cbMaxSignature;
  ULONG cbBlockSize;
  ULONG cbSecurityTrailer;
} SecPkgContext_Sizes, *PSecPkgContext_Sizes;
```

The JNA library (I'm using jna-4.2.2 and jna-platform-4.2.2) provides an implementation in the Secur32 for some of the functions in that .dll. The definitions for the structures are at:
[SecPkgContext_Names structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380089(v=vs.85).aspx), 
[SecPkgInfo structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380104(v=vs.85).aspx), and 
[SecPkgContext_Sizes structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380097(v=vs.85).aspx)

I therefore have defined the following:

```
public interface ISecur32 extends Secur32 {
  // get own copy of the INSTANCE variable
  ISecur32 INSTANCE = (ISecur32) Native.loadLibrary("Secur32",
      ISecur32.class,
      W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);

   // method definition to match
   public int QueryContextAttributes(CtxtHandle phContext,
                                     int SECPKG_ATTR,
                                     PointerByReference pp);

   //
   // for the SECPKG_ATTR_NAMES call
   // NOTE: this definition and invocation is working
   //
   public static class SecPkgContext_Names extends Structure {
      public Pointer pName;

      public SecPkgContext_Names(Pointer p)
      { super(p); }

      @Override
      protected List<?> getFieldOrder()
      { return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "pName" }); }    
    }

    //
    // for the SECPKG_ATTR_SIZES call
    // NOTE: This invocation is NOT working
    //
    public static class SecPkgContext_SizesBis extends Structure {

      public NativeLong cbMaxToken;
      public NativeLong cbMaxSignature;
      public NativeLong cbBlockSize;
      public NativeLong cbSecurityTrailer;

      public SecPkgContext_SizesBis(Pointer p)
      { super(p); }

      @Override
      protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "cbMaxToken", "cbMaxSignature",
          "cbBlockSize", "cbSecurityTrailer"});
   }
 } //interface
```

The call for the Names (which is working) is:

```
public static void querySecPkgAttr_Names(CtxtHandle phContext) {
    final int SECPKG_ATTR_NAMES = 1;

    PointerByReference pp = new PointerByReference();

    int rc = ISecur32.INSTANCE.QueryContextAttributes(phContext,
        SECPKG_ATTR_NAMES,
        pp);

     if (rc != 0) {
       _log.error("Error in QueryContextAttributes: {}", rc);
       return;
     } 

     Pointer p = pp.getPointer();

     ISecur32.SecPkgContext_Names names = new ISecur32.SecPkgContext_Names(p);

     names.read();
     String name = names.pName.getWideString(0);

     rc = ISecur32.INSTANCE.FreeContextBuffer(p);
    _log.debug("FreeContextBuffer: {}", rc);    
  }
```

When I attempt to obtain the Sizes (specifically, I'm after the cbMaxSignature value), I use the following call:

```
public static int querySecPkgAttr_Sizes(CtxtHandle phContext) {
  final int SECPKG_ATTR_SIZES = 0; // SECPKG_ATTR_SIZES is 0

  PointerByReference pp = new PointerByReference();

  int res =  ISecur32.INSTANCE.QueryContextAttributes(phContext,
        SECPKG_ATTR_SIZES, 
        pp);

   // NOTE: the call is succeeding, so this line is not invoked
   if (res != 0) {
    return new NativeLong(0);
   }

   // NOTE: I have also used pp.getPointer()
   Pointer p = pp.getValue();

   ISecur32.SecPkgContext_Sizes sizes = 
    new ISecur32.SecPkgContext_Sizes(p);

    // THIS LINE THROWS THE Invalid Memory Access Error
    sizes.read();

    NativeLong maxSig = sizes.cbMaxSignature;

    rc = ISecur32.INSTANCE.FreeContextBuffer(p);
    _log.debug("FreeContextBuffer: {}", rc);

    return maxSig.intValue();
  }
```

Using the above call, I receive the Exception stack trace of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.getInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getInt(Pointer.java:601)
at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(Pointer.java:389)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Structure.java:705)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.read(Structure.java:565)
at gov.sandia.dart.sspi.Utils.querySecPkgAttr_Sizes(Utils.java:145)
```

If instead of the `pp.getValue()` call, I use `pp.getPointer()`, I receive (when trying to instantiate the Object, I believe):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure exceeds provided memory bounds
```

I am at a loss as to how to solve this issue.

I apologize for not having a complete program, but to get to the point of having the CtxtHandle needed requires a romp through AcquireCredentialsHandle and [InitializeSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375507(v=vs.85).aspx). I believe these are working appropriately, as the Kerberos ticket is showing in the MSLSA cache (viewable via klist) after the `InitializeSecurityContext` completes.

I also looked at the solution [Waffle](http://code.dblock.org/2010/04/08/pure-java-waffle.html), but it does not set the correct flags for in the initialization loop, and also does not implement QueryContextAttributes, or the ultimate goal in all of this the `MakeSignature` function.

I apologize for the length of the post. If I have omitted any piece of information, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: `PointerByReference.getValue()` is _always_ how you should retrieve a result returned in a passed-in reference.  `getPointer()` gives you the address of the memory holding that value.

Comment: You most likely have an improper structure mapping (you don't provide your mapping of `CtxtHandle` or `SecPkgContext_Sizes`, so I'm betting the error is there).  Run your JVM with `-Djna.dump_memory=true`, and print the structures; that will indicate JNA's layout.  Match that up with a similar native dump of structure size/field alignment.

Comment: @technomage, thank you for the comments. The CtxtHandle is a standard JNA structure. In copying code, the SecPkgContext_Sizes ended up with a "Bis" on the end in the code above; I apologize. I found a solution I present below, though I think there should be a more elegant way of achieving the outcome. I appreciate you taking the time to read and comment upon my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue I was having, though not in a very elegant manner. Rather than attempting to use the a `PointerByReference` in the `QueryContextAttributes` as suggested in the question, I ended up creating multiple method definitions, one for each structure. So I have in the Interface, the approach of:

```
public int QueryContextAttributes(CtxtHandle phContext,
                                int SECPKG_ATTR,
                                SecPkgContext_NegotiationInfo negoInfo);

public static class SecPkgContext_NegotiationInfo extends Structure
{
  public Pointer pPackageInfo;
  public int negotiationState;

  public SecPkgContext_NegotiationInfo() {
    super();
  }

  public SecPkgContext_NegotiationInfo(Pointer p) {
    super(p);
  }

  @Override
  protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "pPackageInfo", "negotiationState" 
    });
  }
} 


public int QueryContextAttributes(CtxtHandle phContext,
                                     int SECPKG_ATTR,
                                     SecPkgContext_Sizes sizes);

public static class SecPkgContext_Sizes extends Structure
{
  public int cbMaxToken;
  public int cbMaxSignature;
  public int cbBlockSize;
  public int cbSecurityTrailer;

  public SecPkgContext_Sizes() {
    super();
  }

  public SecPkgContext_Sizes(Pointer p) {
    super(p);
  }

  @Override
  protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "cbMaxToken", 
      "cbMaxSignature",
      "cbBlockSize",
      "cbSecurityTrailer" 
    });
  }
}
```

And so forth for the few definitions I need.

Ultimately the goal was to get the `MakeSignature` call to work (the `QueryContextAttributes(...)` being a precursor), and I had trouble leveraging the default JNA `SecBufferDesc` structure. I found a pointer to a solution from [JSch SSPI by Joe Khoobyar](https://github.com/joekhoobyar/jsch-sspi/tree/master/src/main/java/name/khoobyar/joe/jsch), and leveraged the basic definition from that site, changing the `NativeLong` objects to `int`, and adding the new required method `getFieldOrder()`.

The `MakeSignature` method, following definitions from Microsoft, was defined in the Interface as:

```
public int MakeSignature(CtxtHandle phContext,
                       int fQOP,
                       ISecur32.SecBufferDesc pMessage,
                       int messageSeqNo);
```

After using the above methods for `QueryContextAttributes` and the modified structure for `SecBufferDesc`, I was able to get a working solution. The Java clients may now leverage the Microsoft SSPI system for SSO to the remote Linux machines.

Comment: This is actually the preferred method of mapping functions which take multi-purpose arguments, since it provides more type safety than the native function itself does.